# .NET Transactionscope options

Tags: c#, .net, transactionscope

I am a newbie in C#. So i was just wondering if anybody can help me figure out how C# works with transactionscope? Because i am a little confused by the definition of it. However, let me explain about my problem a little bit. So that you will get to know what i am trying to achieve.

I have three table adapter declared for three different dataset like this:

```
logTableAdapter logAdap = new logTableAdapter();
measTableAdapter measAdap = new measTableAdapter();
valueTableAdapter valueAdap = new valueTableAdapter();
```

The process to import data is:

1. First I insert a log entry via logAdap.insert() method.
2. Loop through an excel file to grab the measurements and starts inserting via measAdap.insert() method.
3. Foreach measurement i am inserting values via valueAdap.insert() method.

So my question is - since measurement & value has a nested relationship. How can I create a nested transactionscope & when an error occur anywhere (measurement insertion / value insertion) i just want to rollback everything i did. That is i just want to go back to the point before the i inserted the log entry.

Comment: BTW there's no such thing as "C#.NET". It's just "C#".

Answer (score 3):

Quoting this aptly named article: [The definitive TableAdapters + Transactions blog post](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/06/18/the-definitive-tableadapters--transactions-blog-post.aspx).

> if you are working with plural operations inside one TransactionScope, i.e. “GetData” and “Update” both inside a single TransactionScope, or two Update’s within a TransactionScope, you will effectively open two SqlConnections to the single database, and thus unnecessarily promote the transaction from LTM to MSDTC. As a best practice, ALWAYS wrap only a singular operation inside a TransactionScope. Should you choose to wrap multiple operations inside a single TransactionScope, you must in that case manage connection lifetime yourself by extending the partial class definition. In other words, the following code will cause the transaction to promote –

```
using (TransactionScope tsc = new TransactionScope())
{
    tableAdap.GetData() ;
    //Do your transactional work.
    tableAdap.Update() ;
    tsc.Complete() ;
}
```

> But the following code is just fine –

```
using (TransactionScope tsc = new TransactionScope())
{

    tableAdap.OpenConnection() ;
    tableAdap.GetData() ;

    //Do your transactional work.
    tableAdap.Update() ;
    tableAdap.CloseConnection() ;
    tsc.Complete() ;
}
```

So you only need one `TransactionScope`, but with some caveats. Here is the gist, but I encourage you to read through the blog post.

`TableAdapters` aren't the most suitable data access methodology for high-integrity transactional systems. If you need more reliablity you should probably write your operation as a stored procedure, and execute it from you C# code.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need more than one TransactionScope, you can do everything in the same one I think.

Comment: So you think the pseudo logic would be something like this:

`code`
using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
{
 try
 {
  foreach (.....)
      {
   measAdap.InsertMeas(.....);
   foreach (.....)
   {
      valAdap.InsertVal(.....);
   }
  }
  
    measAdap.Commit() ;
    valAdap.Commit();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       measAdap.Rollback();
       valAdap.Rollback();
 }
}
`code`

Comment: @Mystic using that logic the transaction gets promoted to using the distributed transaction coordinator. This SO answer tells you why you probably don't want that: http://bit.ly/gGampm - see my answer for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

As I think that what you were looking for is how to use the TransactonScope, here is what your code would look like, modifying a little bit the example in your comment:

```
using( TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope() ) { 
    try 
    { 
        logAdap.InsertLog(.....);

        foreach (.....)
        {
            measAdap.InsertMeas(.....); 
            foreach (.....)
            {
                valAdap.InsertVal(.....);
            }
        }

        // Complete the transaction
        ts.Complete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    { 
        // Your error handling here.
        // No need to rollback each table adapter. That along with all the 
        // transaction is done for you when exiting the using block without 
        // calling Complete() on the TransactionScope.
    }}
```

This way of using the scope is called implicit transactions and you can get a good overview of that in this MSDN article: [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Having said that, what fencliff mentions is true, as you probably don't want to open multiple connections for your scenario, saving valuable database resources.